# add styles to child components using props.children, react

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am trying to build a component called `ViewLayout`, The purpose of this component is that when used as a wrapper it adds some styles to each child component.

For example

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ViewLayout>
      <div className="left-nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Mobiles</li>
        <li>Electronics</li>
      </div>
      <div className="logo">Logo</div>
      <div className="right-nav">
        <li>Cart</li>
        <li>Profile</li>
      </div>
    </ViewLayout>
  );
}
```

Here the `ViewLayout` has 3 children div's and I want to add `border: 1px solid red` to each child div.

`ViewLayout` component

```js
function ViewLayout(props) {
  console.log(props.children);
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}

export default ViewLayout;
```

So every time `ViewLayout` is used as a wrapper it adds the styles defined to each child component, is it possible to achieve this in react?

Source code link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-w5dwgr?file=App.tsx,ViewLayout.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, for this specific use-case, handling it with CSS seems like the better approach (*as the other answers suggest*), here is a solution for when you really have to modify the children.

Using [`React.Children.map`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) and [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

```
function ViewLayout(props) {
  console.log(props.children);
  const updatedChildren = React.Children.map(props.children,(child, idx) =>
    React.cloneElement(
      child,
      { style: { ...child.props.style, border: '1px solid red' } }
    )
  );
  return <div>{updatedChildren}</div>;
}
```

Updated demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-sc1ubn?file=App.tsx,ViewLayout.tsx

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a className attribute in the div tag of ViewLayout component and use CSS to target the direct div children of that class.

ViewLayout Component:

```
function ViewLayout(props) {
   console.log(props.children);
   return <div>{props.children}</div>;
}

export default ViewLayout;
```

---

CSS file:

```
.viewlayout > div{
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If you want to target every direct child then use * in css, e.g:

```
.viewlayout > * {
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just use css

```
function ViewLayout(props) {
  return <div classname='ViewLayout'>{props.children}</div>;
}

.ViewLayout div{style}
```